# Buildout eggs automagically adding to the paths?

Tags: buildout

Is there any way to automagically add packages from `develop-eggs` to `extra-paths`?

Answer (score 1):

Use mr.developer: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer

It manages develop eggs beautifully, including adding them to develop-eggs in the first place.

Comment: great but I need to add them to extra-paths - there are not so many of them - 2 tops!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to automatically add develop-eggs to *eggs*, rather than extra-paths. extra-paths is more for things that aren't eggy.

If you have an egg 'foo' and an egg 'bar' and you want to create a testrunner for 'foo' but it needs 'bar' on the path as well i would do something like:

```
[buildout]
extensions = isotoma.extensions.autodevelop
parts = test

[test]
recipe = pbp.recipe.noserunner
eggs = foo
defaults = foo
```

And the setup.py for foo would have an install_requires line:

```
setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=['foo'],
    install_requires=['bar']
    )
```

The autodevelop extension will automatically find source eggs in the same folder as the buildout.cfg by looking for setup.py and adding them to the list of develop eggs. And buildout will get the paths of the tester right because it looks at the dependencies of 'foo' and sees 'bar' needs to be on the path as well. This will be true of any recipe that takes a list of eggs.

If you want to automatically update the list of eggs, look at buildout.eggtractor. I do not recommend this however. Your buildout should be explicit about what eggs it is using (i mean uses directly, you only have to list foo in my example because it depends on bar) and your eggs should be explicit about the dependencies they have. That way if you ever want to deploy from eggs you have no extra work to do.

Comment: What advantages does isotoma.extensions.autodevelop offer over mr.developer?

Comment: mr.developer is great if you want to automate checkouting out packages  but you might already have them checked out through other means.


I used autodevelop in my reply because OP was asking about how to get them added to the path, not how to get them there at all. If his buildout is in the same checkout as his eggs then mr.developer wont help?

He really just needs to make sure his eggs are in ${buildout:eggs} (or equivalent recipe variable) and then extra-paths won't matter.

Comment: mr.developer would still help; use the 'fs' option to mark a package as already present and it'll still provide all the other management options still, such as activating and deactivating.

Comment: I completely agree about not needing extra-paths if the package is an egg though. :-)